# Can I get a feedback of whether the onstorage event was caught by other pages in the page fired the event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Example：
Page A:playlist page;
Page B:player page;
When click the playlist, add src to localStorage, if player page is opened, it will catch the onstorage event and do response(play), if not opened, how should I do? What can I think of is when click the palylist, set a timer to open the player page(when player page caught the onstorage event, set an item to localStorage for the playlist page to catch, if the playlist page catch the event, it can clear the timer), but this will get a delay if player page is not opened. Any better solution? Thanks.

Comment: "Catched" isn't a word. Do you mean "caught" or "cached"?

Comment: Actually, the whole title may need to be rephrased because an event can be neither caught nor cached.